# Javascript reduce, don't display category if there's no element to show

Tags: javascript, ejs

I've a data that comes from the database, which I filter and group the item based on the category field and then I display the items with their corresponding category and here's the code I got **I'm using EJS as a templating engine** :

```
<% 

var catDocs =   docs.reduce((acc, x) => {
    acc[x.datas.category] = [...(acc[x.datas.category] || []), x];
    return acc;
}, {});

Object.entries(catDocs).map(function ([cat, items]){ %>
  <h4 class="category"><%=ucfirst(cat)%></h4>
<div class="row">
  <%
    items.filter(function(item) {
      if (!datas.loggedIn && item.datas.status !== 'published') {
return false; // skip
      }
      return true;
    }).map(function (item) {%> 


    <h5><%= item.datas.status %></h5>

    <% }); 

}); %>
```

And here's the original data before the `reduce` :

[image: Original Data]

Now I'm stuck in a bug, some categories does not have any published item and the title still shows because I'm showing the title before I use the `filter` function, where I skip every item that's not published while the user is not logged in.

If anyone can help to hide the title if there's no item to show **(in other words if `if there's not any pushblished item and there's is not logged in don't display the corresponding title`)**

Thank you so much to everyone for helping.

Best Regards

Comment: Please post your `docs` content.

Comment: @sandrooco I've added a screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want to filter out only the entries with either truthy `loggedIn` property, or status "published"? Start with that.

```
catDocs =  docs
   .filter(({ datas }) => datas.loggedIn || datas.status === 'published')
   .reduce((acc, x) => { // the rest here
```

BTW, this isn't a good reducer function, mutating the accumulator instead of *only* returning a new value.

Answer (score 0):

It’s better to prepare the data into structure where it’s easier for your view to render.

E.g. map and filter datas.docs first to new array that has only category=>items pairs where items.length > 0

Also move the !datas.loggedIn check outside of your filter, since you don’t want to render anything if user is not logged in. That’s just normal if clause before anything else in your example.

Comment: Could you show me by code how can I do it, I've added a screenshot of the original data.